# The limit for the function of the following two variables?

Tags: limits

If I understand correctly, there is no L'Hôpital's Rule for two variables.

I wanted to know what is the limit for:

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (\infty ,\infty)} \frac{x}{y}=?$$

And also:

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (\infty ,\infty)} \frac{xy}{xy}=?$$

And lastly:

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (\infty ,\infty)} \frac{xy-x-y}{\sqrt{x^2-x}\sqrt{y^2-y}}=?$$

I suspect all of them "should" be 1.

But I am not sure what reasoning/constraints are needed in order to claim that.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all you should make clear what you mean by $\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)}$.

Comment: You can evaluate double variable limits by changing to the polar coordinate frame, i.e, $(x,y)$->$(r,$$alpha$$)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first limit doesn't exist because for any $K>0$, you can choose $x=Ky$ so the limit, if it existed, would be $K$.  Since $K$ can be any positive number you want, the limit doesn't exist. For this limit to exist you need some "constraints" as you mentioned.

The second limit really is $1$ because $(xy)/(xy)=1$ for $x,y \neq 0$.

The third limit is $1$.  Divide numerator and denominator by $xy$ and simplify.  The numerator and denominator both approach $1$ as $(x,y) \to (\infty,\infty)$.